# jQuery slideDown delayed at end

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidedown

At http://teneo.telegraphbranding.com/index.php/, when the 'About' link is clicked on the sidbar a dropdown is triggered. However, it stutters at the end before finally finishing. I'm stumped. Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('h3.about').on('click', function() {
    $('.dropdown').slideDown(function() {
        window.parent.location = '/about.php'
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: shouldn't the first parameter in the slideDown function be a duration?

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: If you leave the duration out it just goes to default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem for `inline` elements. You can add your `h1` to `div` and animate this one or specify css `display: block` for header.

Comment: I tried putting each <h4> in its own div but that didn't work. I also changed the h4's to display: block and that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any "shutters" _during the animation_. You load _another_ page and it takes a while to load resources and render page.

Comment: To avoid this problem, you should use a single page, and download content using Ajax.

Comment: Another other possibility is to do the menu slidedown onpageload of your about page.

However, I agree with Andrey's suggestion.  Causing the page to redirect will require loading content, which will create a choppy interface.  jQuery was developed to give the developer more power over DOM access and manipulation which is common in rich application interfaces.  Animations shouldn't be interrupted with page redirects/reloads.